# How do I plot the densities from a histogram?

Tags: r, histogram

So I want to do something like this in R:

```
 x <- rnorm(1000, 100, 50)
 h <- hist(x, breaks="fd")
 z <- plot(h$breaks, h$density)
```

The problem is that the $breaks field in the histogram has one more value than the $density field? is there an easy way around this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out all I needed to do was to set the  `freq`  field to `FALSE`

So I just did  `hist(rnorm(1000, 100, 50), freq="FALSE")` and that did a histogram of relative frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what the problem is, but you could just drop either the first or last element of `h$breaks` to plot the points at either endpoint, or you could drop the last element and then add half the bin width to plot them at the midpoints:

```
plot(h$breaks[-length(h$breaks)] + 5, h$density)
```

That just fixes your specific problem, though. There may be a better way of using `hist` in general, if you expanded on what you're trying to do a bit.